# How to edit the footer in the wordpress editor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am newbie to wordpress website creation, and i am trying to edit the footer of the website, basically the copyright text of the footer and want to add more things in the footer, i am not getting any option under 'appearance', 'theme options', and 'theme file editor'

how can i edit the things there?

i have tried the chatgpt, bard ai for the solutions but no good for this issue

the theme i am using is Chique Music.

if i tried to edit it by omitting this line of code in `footer.php` then everything gets deleted for the footer section

```
            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/footer/site', 'info' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function, get_template_part (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) pulls in another php file, and that's the one you need to edit.  You can see where that file is by looking at the arguments, but you have to know that you combine the arguments together with a dash and add .php.  Here is the file you are looking for (inside the theme folder):

/template-parts/footer/site-info.php

Browse to that file and you'll probably find the copyright inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I did the the customization by editing the parent theme's footer.php's site-info.php file